# What are the tradeoffs between the Haskell SQLite packages?

Tags: haskell, sqlite

There are many Haskell SQLite bindings, which implies to me that there are many different tradeoffs on using building/using a SQLite binding. I've tried to read through the documentation of many of these packages but it became a blur after a while, and I was unable to really identify the primary tradeoffs of choosing one over another.

A search on Hackage finds:

- [direct-sqlite](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/direct-sqlite)
- [HDBC-sqlite3](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HDBC-sqlite3)
- [hdbi-sqlite](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hdbi-sqlite)
- [hsql-sqlite3](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hsql-sqlite3)
- [hsSqlite3](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hsSqlite3)
- [persistent-sqlite](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-sqlite)
- [simplest-sqlite](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/simplest-sqlite)
- [sql-simple-sqlite](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sql-simple-sqlite)
- [sqlite](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sqlite)
- [sqlite-simple](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sqlite-simple)
- [sqlite-simple-typed](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sqlite-simple-typed)
- [bindings-sqlite3](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bindings-sqlite3)

Nevermind some "meta" SQLite packages. [haskelldb-hdbc-sqlite3](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskelldb-hdbc-sqlite3), [haskelldb-hsql-sqlite3](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskelldb-hsql-sqlite3), [language-sqlite](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/language-sqlite), [opaleye-sqlite](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/opaleye-sqlite)

Hoping that someone has been able to do this successfully and can help me understand how to choose.

Answer (score 6):

I looked at the package mentioned. Some of these package are a dependency of another package (like opaleye-sqlite and sqlite-simple) depend on direct-sqlite.

Therefore, let's first look at the package that provide the actual driver. Most of them are outdated. There seem to be 3 that still have recent updates:

- https://hackage.haskell.org/package/simplest-sqlite https://github.com/YoshikuniJujo/test_haskell/tree/master/features/ffi/sqlite3/simplest-sqlite i wouldn't use it because the repository says "It's just my private Haskell learning/testing repository."
- https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-sqlite this one is based on direct-sqlite (seems like part of the direct-sqlite has been forked)
- The last one being the direct-sqlite package. I used [this website](https://packdeps.haskellers.com/reverse/direct-sqlite) to find which package depend on direct-sqlite. Now leaving out package that don't have the purpose of working with sqlite (such as bake: Continuous integration system). And also leaving out packages that haven't seen updates in a long time.

That leaves us with the following package that provide extra functionality based on direct-sqlite. This list includes more levels of reverse lookup to see which other package make use of the package listed below.

- [persistent-sqlite](https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/tree/master/persistent-sqlite) as mentioned before

  - [esqueleto](https://github.com/bitemyapp/esqueleto)
  - [eventful](https://github.com/jdreaver/eventful)
- [groundhog-sqlite](https://github.com/lykahb/groundhog)
- [opaleye-sqlite](https://github.com/tomjaguarpaw/haskell-opaleye)
- [selda-sqlite](https://github.com/valderman/selda)
- [sqlite-simple](https://github.com/nurpax/sqlite-simple)

  - [beam-sqlite](https://github.com/tathougies/beam)

Answer (score 5):

I've had very good experiences with the ...-simple family of libraries.  They are very full-featured and sit at a nice medium level of abstraction where you get a large amount of flexibility over how you intereact with the database.

I'm the author of [opaleye-sqlite](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/opaleye-sqlite).  It is a somewhat experimental version of Opaleye for SQLite.  The Postgres version of Opaleye is very solid and used in production in several places, but I only know of one person who has used opaleye-sqlite in production.

Comment: I should point out that in the intervening five years opaleye-sqlite has become unmaintained.  It could be brought up to date but would require someone to put in the effort.